# How can a file based ResourceManager fall back to the embedded resources?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resources, resourcemanager

Our winforms application needs to be able to distribute ad-hoc translations in the *.resource format and use these in preference to the embedded translations. Is there a way to acheive this fall back strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new class that can contain two `ResourceManager`s. These can be both a file based `ResourceManager` for the ad-hoc *.resource files and an assembly based `ResourceManager` for the embedded resource files.

If the ad-hock mode is enabled then the primary `ResourceManager` is file based with the second `ResourceManager` as an assembly based one used in a `catch` block as a fall back.

If the ad-hoc mode is dissabled the primary `ResourceManager` is an assembly based one and there is no secondary `ResourceManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Why the *.resource format.  The .Net pattern is to use localised DLL files. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688110.aspx

Comment: Because these need to be distributed ad-hock, it's in the question! They are in addition to the main assembly and satelite assembly embedded resources.